# General solution of a differential equation with exponantial terms

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

How can I get a general solution to the following ode?
dsolve command in  Wolfram Mathematica and Maple don't return any result
[image]

```
DSolve[((5 (-10 + 3 E^(t \[Alpha])) \[Alpha]^2)/(
      9 (-1 + E^(t \[Alpha]))^2) + (
      E^(2 t \[Alpha]) (-1 + E^(-t \[Alpha]))^(
       1/3) \[CapitalOmega]^2)/((-1 + E^(t \[Alpha]))^2 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(a\), \(0\), \(2\)]\))) T[t] - (
   5 E^(-t \[Alpha]) \[Alpha] T'[t])/(
   2 (-1 + E^(-t \[Alpha]))) + T''[t] == 0, {T[t], 
  T[t]}, {t}]
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Change `(T^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]` to `T''[t]`- But ode can't be solved analytically. I also tried transformation `T[t]==F[u=Exp[\[Alpha]t]` but it remains unsolvable.

Comment: The sub `t -> -(Log[1 + v^3]/\[Alpha])` turns the DE into a holonomic one that yields a `DifferentialRoot` solution, probably with branch-cut/singularity issues, which I could not resolve because I couldn't get the solution to evaluate.